# How to create apps with same look and feel across platforms with Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I just recently decided to give NativeScript a try since I want to re-use my exp with Angular, but I wanted to know if it's possible to create an app that has the same or most similar styling across devices, like Youtube or Instagram for example, they are practically the same screens in different devices. If that's possible can I get a high level explanation of how this can be accomplished with NativeScript? I followed some tutorials and the first thing you notice is how the different tags translate to the different native components between Android and iOS, they are a lot of times very very different in style.

Edit: See the examples I gave, youtube and Instagram, I'm not talking about bringing Android materials to iOS or vice-versa. I'm talking about having a specific styling equal in both platforms.

Comment: What you mean by same look, by default Android uses Material Design and iOS uses it's own flat design standards. If you are planning to bring iOS look and feel on Android it may be easy with the available CSS stylings. But if you like Android's material stylings on iOS, it may be hard. You might have to use the official material UI for [iOS](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios) and [Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android). Unfortunately there are no plugins yet for these libraries, hence you will have write one/directly access it.

Comment: I see there's some confusion of what I'm asking, see my Edit.

Comment: Daniel, I think it is possible. Sometimes you need to add some additional styles which are different for iOS and Android to achieve the same look. Sometimes you will have to create your own component from scratch if {N} doesn't give you an option to style as you would want. And have you seen code-sharing feature? It could help too: https://docs.nativescript.org/code-sharing/intro

Comment: Thanks for the info @SebastianDenis that's what I wanted to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found that the best way to do this is by using platform-specific css to tweak and modify in order to achieve the same look in both platforms, more info here [Platform-Specific CSS](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/styling#platform-specific-css)